# Android studio running app on Samsung Galaxy S3 hangs at Uploading file

Tags: android, android-studio, galaxy

My app with only one activity runs perfect on all emulators including the Samsung Galaxy S3 emulator provided by Genymotion. I am using the Android Studio.

When I hook up my real Samsung Galaxy S3 to my computer it reads the device correct and it is online with all the correct developer options. It's correctly listed by adb as "device".

I am targeting the correct API (18) for my device I believe, android 4.3

This is where it gets "stuck" and nothing happens on the real device:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Have you enabled developer mode on the device?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had problem such that with the N10 tablet. It was caused by bad quality USB port/cable. Problem dissapeared when I connected cable to the mainboard USB instead chassis one.

Comment: Strange. I was uploading app for 3 hours and it worked. Than stopped and only your solution had worked. Super strange...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're getting that certain error, but you can install the app on your phone by using Build->Generate Signed APK, then emailing yourself the APK, and downloading it on your phone. Also, a reboot might fix the "stuck" part.

Comment: This solution also works but I can't accept two answers so I picked the more direct answer.

Comment: That's fine, as long as it works for you, I'm happy.