# Android studio running app on Huawei G700 hangs at Uploading file

Tags: android, android-studio

I know Android Studio is currently in beta, but still maybe somebody has a solution to this. Similar to [Android studio running app on Samsung Galaxy S3 hangs at Uploading file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22464012/android-studio-running-app-on-samsung-galaxy-s3-hangs-at-uploading-file) I have issues when trying to run my app. It doesn't actually matter if its the physical phone or the android emulator.

I've tried with my app and a new empty project: same result. After compilation it tries to upload the app and just gets stuck. I've tried re-installation of Androidstudio and rebooting. Fun fact: on my laptop everything works just fine.

Any more ideas would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Note: I already tried to switch the USB Cable, still nothing better. I actually checked to do the upload directly via the shell, same result. Might this be a local issue of the machine e.g. drivers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So actually it looks like something with the Platform tools was going wrong. A delete and install in the SDK Manager solved my issue. Weird, that the tools coming with the studio bundle are broken on my system.

Comment: So after some more testing, it appears this happens quite often. Some Process or similar must be broken at a certain point and only a reinstallation of the tool solves this. Can't really say why this is happening...

Answer (score 0):

Go to build and Rebuild your project. It will solve the problem.